# Using os.path for POSIX Path Operations on Windows

Tags: python, windows, path, posix

I'm using Paramiko on Windows to access a remote SFTP server. I need to do some work with remote paths like `os.path.join`, `os.path.commonprefix`, etc. Since my host platform is Windows, all paths operations come with the `\` separator, but I need POSIX-styled paths.

Is there any way to use Python built-in POSIX path operations on Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As pointed out in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) (2nd note)

> ... you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to
>   manipulate a path that is *always* in one of the different formats. They
>   all have the same interface:
>
> - `posixpath` for UNIX-style paths
> - `ntpath` for Windows paths

So you could import `posixpath` and use it as `os.path`

```
>>> import posixpath
>>> posixpath.join
<function join at 0x025C4170>
>>> posixpath.join('a','b')
'a/b'
>>> posixpath.commonprefix
<function commonprefix at 0x00578030>
```

Comment: You could also use [`pathlib.PurePosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePosixPath).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [pathlib.PurePosixPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePosixPath) is the way to go (as already commented by [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1398841/phoenix)).

E.g.:

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> pathlib.PurePosixPath('a', 'b')
PurePosixPath('a/b')
>>> str(pathlib.PurePosixPath('a', 'b'))
'a/b'
```

From the depending docs:

> class pathlib.PurePosixPath(*pathsegments)
>
> A subclass of PurePath, this path flavour represents non-Windows filesystem paths:
>
> ```
> >>> PurePosixPath('/etc')
> PurePosixPath('/etc')
> ```
>
> pathsegments is specified similarly to PurePath.
>
> class pathlib.PureWindowsPath(*pathsegments)
>
> A subclass of PurePath, this path flavour represents Windows filesystem paths:
>
> ```
> >>> PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files/')
> PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files')
> ```
>
> pathsegments is specified similarly to PurePath.
>
> Regardless of the system you’re running on, you can instantiate all of
> these classes, since they don’t provide any operation that does system
> calls.